# I get application-defined or object-defined error on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim xRange As Range 
a = 0  'for matchting the coordinates and making them a list'

For i = 1 To 10 'for changing the selected row'

    Set xRange = Sheets("sayfa4").Rows(i) ''for finding min value between the rows's cell'

        For j = 1 To 10 'for column'
            If Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j) > 0 And Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(xRange) Then 'this looks for do cell have a value , and is this value row's min one?'
                If (i = 1 And j = 10) Or (i = 2 And j = 9) Or (i = 7 And j = 8) Or (i = 10 And j = 1) Or (i = 9 And j = 2) Or (i = 8 And j = 7) Then
                    a = a + 1
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j).ClearContents 'deleting the cell if it is suiatable for the condition'
                
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 1) = i 'printing the cells row value'
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 2) = j 'printing the cells column value'
                 
                Else
                
                    a = a + 1
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j).ClearContents 'deleting the cell's value'
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(j, i).ClearContents 'deleting the symmetrical coordinates, cause i have two dimentional distance matrix'
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 1) = i
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 2) = j
                
                End If
            
                  
            End If
            
        Next j
        
Next i
```

well i don't know why i got this error actually it stops at

```
Else

                a = a + 1
               > Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j).ClearContents
                Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(j, i).ClearContents
                Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 1) = i
                Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 2) = j
```

right there actually , i am trying to solve a problem about edge routing and i thought this code may solve my problem but i got the error after the "Else" i was trying to solve this problem about 2 weeks actually i am newbie on it
if you will as why you have a lot of coordinates in if condition , i am working on a problem for Eulerian Tour and in this case i need to select enough edges beetwen nodes for repeating the edge , this will create the Eulerian Tour and making the mathematical constraints approved , the selected nodes are ODD ones and when i repeat the edge between the odd nodes they are becoming "even" node so by this way i am creating the shortest path for Chinese Postman Problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the information you have provided. Suggest you read HELP for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , and then edit your question to provide more detailed information.

Comment: Well sorry at first , i have been in courses , i tried to edit for clarifying with extra comments on it i hope it will be clearly understandable